# function.createdelegate

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, delegates

how can i call 2 methods using function.createdelgate()

lik i'm having

2 methods (method_one and method_two)

```
Function.CreateDelegate(this,method_one);
```

but i need to call both the methods in it...

Answer (score 3):

Write method_three that calls method_one and method_two then create a delegate for that method.